# Multi color scatter plot using matplotlib.pyplot based on input field from CSV

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I want a scatter plot, where each point is colored based on the tags:
Same tags should be plotted with the same colored points.

```
eg: tag: 'One', color : red
    tag: 'Two', color : green
```

Intput CSV file: (first column is the tag)

```
One;0;0.2345;0.43543;
Two;0.2345;0;0.34563;
One;0.43543;0.34563;0;
```

Plotting code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import manifold
reader = csv.reader(open("data.csv", "r"), delimiter=';')
data = list(reader)

dists = []
tags = []
for d in data:
    tags.append(d[0])
    dists.append(map(float , d[1:-1]))

adist = np.array(dists)
amax = np.amax(adist)
adist /= amax

mds = manifold.MDS(n_components=2, dissimilarity="precomputed", random_state=10)
results = mds.fit(adist)

coords = results.embedding_

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0.1)
plt.scatter(coords[:, 0], coords[:, 1], marker = 'o')
for label, x, y in zip(tags, coords[:, 0], coords[:, 1]):
    plt.annotate(
        label,
        xy = (x, y), xytext = (-8, 8),
        textcoords = 'offset points', ha = 'right', va = 'bottom',
        bbox = dict(boxstyle = 'round,pad=0.2', fc = 'blue', alpha = 0.1),
        arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '->', connectionstyle = 'arc3,rad=0'))

plt.show()
```

Right now all the points displayed are of the same color. 
I want each point to be of a different color, based on the string value of tags. 
The color can be picked from a map in python

```
{one:red, two:green, three:yellow}
```

Comment: It's not quite obvious what your question/problem is?

Comment: I have edited the question, hope this would make my question clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have more than just plotting in your code, I'll suggest a solution with minimum changes to your code so that you can incorporate it easily:

- Create a dict for color selection: `color_dict = {'One':'red', 'Two':'green', 'Three':'yellow'}`
- Plot points one by one, by moving `plt.scatter()` into the `for` loop and change it into `plt.scatter(x, y, c=color_dict[label], marker = 'o')`

A complete updated example and its result:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import manifold
reader = csv.reader(open("data.csv", "r"), delimiter=';')
data = list(reader)

dists = []
tags = []
for d in data:
    tags.append(d[0])
    dists.append(map(float , d[1:-1]))

adist = np.array(dists)
amax = np.amax(adist)
adist /= amax

mds = manifold.MDS(n_components=2, dissimilarity="precomputed", random_state=10)
results = mds.fit(adist)

coords = results.embedding_

color_dict = {'One':'red', 'Two':'green', 'Three':'yellow'}

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0.1)
#plt.scatter(coords[:, 0], coords[:, 1], marker = 'o')
for label, x, y in zip(tags, coords[:, 0], coords[:, 1]):
    plt.scatter(x, y, c=color_dict[label], marker = 'o')
    plt.annotate(
        label,
        xy = (x, y), xytext = (-8, 8),
        textcoords = 'offset points', ha = 'right', va = 'bottom',
        bbox = dict(boxstyle = 'round,pad=0.2', fc = 'blue', alpha = 0.1),
        arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '->', connectionstyle = 'arc3,rad=0'))

plt.show()
```

[image]